# How to view image created in a python script on docker

Tags: docker

I've built a docker container using a dockerfile which contained a python command on how to generate a dataset image.

It says it has been successfully built, but how do I view if the image has actually generated properly?

Comment: Run `docker images` to see if the image has been generated

Comment: If the image is generated run `docker run <imagename>` to check if image is working fine

Comment: @DeepakPatankar yes it has been generated and runs  but I want to physically view it

Comment: You can try `docker logs` to get the logs of the container. This way you will be able to see your python command running, https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/logs/